# how to modify time range in interactive chat?

Tags: openfda

Deadlines are always up to date in interactive chat ,for example:i want to query time range between 2015/01/01-2020/01/01.how to modify?

Answer (score 0):

The interactive charts have the "Custom search parameter" box (bottom left), in which you can type in a custom search parameter, and then press Enter to update the chart. Please see an example below:

[image]